# Shell: Capturing output files in variables

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

Commands like `openssl` have arguments like `-out <file>` for output files. I'd like to capture the content of these output files in shell variables for use in other commands without creating temporary files. For example, to generate a self-signed certificate, one can use:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj / -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout KEYFILE -out CERTFILE 2>/dev/null
```

The closest I've got to capture both output files is to echo them to stdout via process substitution but this is not ideal because one would still have to parse them apart.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj / -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout >(key=$(cat -); echo $key) -out >(cert=$(cat -); echo $cert) 2>/dev/null
```

Is there a clean way to capture the content of output files in shell variables?

Comment: Please tag for only one shell. `sh`, `bash` and `zsh` are in many respects mutually incompatible; only a lowest-common-denominator answer  (using a lot of extra code -- such as setting up named FIFOs -- for compatibility) will work for all three. Process substitutions such as `>(...)` won't work at all in `sh`, f/e; and some of the code you use in our samples (ie. `echo $key`) are safe only in zsh, and not in *either* of the others.

Comment: ...that said, as much as you may not like it, the least-hacky, most-reliable solution here *will* be to use temporary files. Even the named FIFO approach is going to have some nasty failure cases (wherein `openssl` failures that don't write to the FIFOs at all leave the shell hanging waiting for output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern shells now support /dev/stdout as a file name to redirect to stdout. This is good enough for single file solutions but for two output files you need to go with "process substitution".

```
eval "$( openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj / -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout >(echo "keyout='$( cat )'" ) -out >(echo out="'$( cat )'" ) )"
```

This uses process substitution to direct each "file" to a separate process that prints to stdout an assignment of the calculated values. The whole thing is then passed to an eval to do the actual assignments.

Keeping output of stderr to show any error messages that pops up. Useful to log it in times of troubles.

Edit: incorporating [Charles Duffy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491899/693294) good paranoia:

```
flockf="$(mktemp -t tmp.lock.$$.XXXXXX )" || exit $?;

eval "$( openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj / -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
        -keyout >( set -x; 99>"$flockf" && \
                flock -x "$flockf" printf "keyout=%q " "$( cat )"; ) \ 
        -out    >( set -x; 99>"$flockf" && \
                flock -x "$flockf" printf "out=%q "    "$( cat )"; ) \ 
        )"  ;
rm -f "$flockf"
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I'm all for paranoia - yes, should have used printf %q..

Comment: As an aside -- no need for the `$?` in `exit $?`, as `$?` is the default status used by `exit`.

Comment: Happy to see the change adopted; leaving my answer around only to have a reproducer for the security bug on the record for anyone wondering *why* this is necessary.

Comment: That said, I'm surprised to see `99>"$flockf"` without a preceding `exec` leave the FD open for future commands, as opposed to just opening it transiently. Which shell was this tested on?

Comment: ...oh -- I see why that appeared to work. Oops -- that's a mistake I made in my answer; now edited to lock via the FD, not the name, so the lock is held through the `printf`, rather than for a transient period preceding it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out eval(), that was the piece I was missing. It's a bit of a shame that there's no other way to to content out of a `()` block, so one needs to take care what is eval'ed.

Comment: `flock printf` doesn't necessarily work, because when `flock` invokes `printf` it's using an external invocation -- `/usr/bin/printf`, not the shell-builtin one. While bash is provides a `printf` that supports `%q`, the external one in the PATH [isn't certain to have that feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html).

Answer (score 2):

An extension to [Gilbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491396/14122) providing additional paranoia:

```
eval "$( openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj / -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
         -keyout >(printf 'keyout=%q\n' "$(</dev/stdin)") \
         -out >(printf 'out=%q\n' "$(</dev/stdin)") )"
```

(Note that this is not suitable if your data contains NULs, which bash cannot store in a native shell variable; in that case, you'll want to assign the contents to your variables in `base64`-encoded form).

Unlike `echo "keyout='$(cat)'"`, `printf 'keyout=%q\n' "$(cat)"` ensures that even malicious contents cannot be `eval`uated by the shell as a command substitution, redirection, or otherwise content other than literal data.

---

To explain why this is necessary, let's take a simplified case:

```
write_to_two_files() { printf 'one\n' >"$1"; printf 'two\n' >"$2"; }
write_to_two_files >(echo "one='$(cat)'") >(echo "two='$(cat)'")
```

...we get output akin to (but with no particular ordering):

```
two='two'
one='one'
```

...which, when `eval`ed, sets two variables:

```
$ eval "$(write_to_two_files >(echo "one='$(cat)'") >(echo "two='$(cat)'"))"
$ declare -p one two
declare -- one="one"
declare -- two="two"
```

However, let's say that our program behaves a bit differently:

```
## Demonstrate why eval'ing content created by echoing data is dangerous
write_to_two_files() {
  printf "'%s'\n" '$(touch /tmp/i-pwned-your-box)' >"$1"
  echo "two" >"$2"
}
eval "$(write_to_two_files >(echo "one='$(cat)'") >(echo "two='$(cat)'"))"
ls -l /tmp/i-pwned-your-box
```

Instead of merely assigning the output to a variable, we *evaluated it as code*.

---

If you're further interested in ensuring that the two print operations happen at different times (preventing their output from being intermingled), it's useful to further add locking. This *does* involve a temporary file, but *does not* write your keying material to disk (avoidance of which is the most compelling reason to avoid temporary file usage):

```
lockfile=$(mktemp -t output.lck.XXXXXX)
eval "$( openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj / -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
         -keyout >(in=$(cat); exec 99>"$lockfile" && flock -x 99 && printf 'keyout=%q\n' "$in") \
         -out    >(in=$(cat); exec 99>"$lockfile" && flock -x 99 && printf 'out=%q\n' "$in") )"
```

Note that we're only blocking for the write, not the read, so we can't get into race conditions (ie. where openssl isn't finishing writing to file-A because it's blocked on a write to file-B, which can never complete because the subshell on the read side of the file-A write holds the lock).

Comment: If you are just a guy, see, I suppose you k now where your towel is. Anyway, thanks for the interactionI'ts been awhile since I've found someone I can seriously learn more shell stuff from. Not sure you will see this, but thanks. Going through some of your answers elsewhere. Gilbert.